# How do you print the text from a file in Lua?

Tags: file, printing, io, lua

I would like to be able to print the text from a file.  When I use `print(io.open(filename,r))`, it gives me the file name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`io.open` returns a file handle, to read the content, you need `io.read`:

```
local f = io.open(filename,r)
print(f:read("*a"))
```

Learn about IO from [The I/O Library](http://www.lua.org/pil/21.html).

Comment: A successful call to `io.open` should eventually be followed by `f:close()`.